# React Promise for strange API error with nested objects

Tags: reactjs, google-books

I'm working with GoogleBooks API and I can get from the API the object that I need, and from there all the values I want. e.g.

```
  console.log("item", item); // full object
  console.log("title", item.volumeInfo.title); // title
```

but when I want to get nested objects I get an error:

```
console.log(item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail);

TypeError: Cannot read property 'smallThumbnail' of undefined
```

So I created a  this:

```
const BookItem = ({ item }) => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

...

```
useEffect(() => {
const objSource = item.volumeInfo.imageLinks;
const getImages = Object.values(objSource);
console.log(getImages);
//eslint-disable-next-line
}, []);

const clickAddToStore = () => {
    setAddToStore(true);
  };
  const clickRemoveFromStore = () => {
    setAddToStore(false);
  };

  const addToDb = () => {
    dispatch(
      addToWooDb(
        item.volumeInfo,
        item.searchInfo,
        stockQuantity,
        bookStatus,
        price
      )
    );
  };

  return (

 <div
 className="item3"
 onClick={!addToStore ? clickAddToStore : clickRemoveFromStore}
 >
 {item.volumeInfo.title}
 </div>
```

...

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  data: state.items,
  loading: state.items.loading,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addToWooDb })(BookItem);
```

and works perfectly, hence I can see in the console:

```
["http://books.google.com/books/content?id=3nMEPQAAC…J&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api", "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=3nMEPQAAC…J&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api"]
0: "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=3nMEPQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api"
1: "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=3nMEPQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api"
```

But strangely I still get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

I think that I can solve it with a promise, but I never understood how they work.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the full code?

Comment: thanks. I did it. Just the most important parts cause it's really long

Comment: Why do you do sometimes item.volumeInfo and othertimes item.item.volumeInfo?

Comment: simply a mistake from cut and paste differetn versions. thisi is NOT the problem